# Simplify combining multiple table variables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the code below (obviously with some changed names). I'm trying to find a simpler or more-effective way to create the same results. Any suggestions appreciated. THIS IS FOR FUN. MINE ALREADY WORKS

```
DECLARE @Scenes TABLE(IncNo numeric(12,0), SceneSquad int, ScDate datetime)
INSERT INTO @Scenes 
SELECT A.IncNo, SceneSquad, ScDate 
FROM DATABASE as A
LEFT JOIN DATABASE as B
On A.IncNo = B.IncNo
WHERE ScDate BETWEEN '1/1/2021' AND '10/31/2021'
AND A.DivID = ''

DECLARE @Assigned TABLE(IncNo numeric(12,0), Followupsquad int, AssignmentDate 
datetime)
INSERT INTO @Assigned 
SELECT IncNo, Followupsquad, ASSIGNMENTDATE
FROM DATABASE AS C
LEFT JOIN DATABASE AS D
ON D.IncNo = C.CIncNo
WHERE SOMETHING = 'Y' AND DateRuled BETWEEN '1/1/2021' AND '10/31/2021'
AND D.AssignD = ''

DECLARE @Squads TABLE(Squad int, RN int)
INSERT INTO @Squads 
SELECT Squad, ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY Squad) AS E 
FROM DATABASE
WHERE UnitType = '' AND DivId = '' AND SquadStatus = 'A'
ORDER BY Squad


DECLARE @MSS TABLE (SqdNo int,  SOMETHING int, SOMETHINGELSE int)

    DECLARE @DATE datetime, @X int, @SQ int,  @M int, @S int
    SET @DATE = 1/1/2021 - 10/31/2021
    SET @X = 1

    WHILE @X <= (SELECT MAX(RN) FROM @Squads)
    BEGIN
    SET @SQ = (SELECT Squad FROM @Squads WHERE RN = @X)
    SET @S = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @Scenes WHERE SceneSquad = @SQ)
    SET @M = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @Assigned WHERE Followupsquad = @SQ)

    INSERT INTO @MSS VALUES (@SQ,  @M, @S)
    SET @X = @X + 1
    END

SELECT SqdNo , SOMETHING , SOMETHINGELSE 
FROM @MSS
```

Comment: Getting rid of the `WHILE` would *vastly* improve it. Though we have no idea what the above is supposed to be doing, so no idea how to actually improve it. I suggest researching set-based methodology.

Comment: without the `while` statement I wouldn't result with all the row numbers I need.... only the first

Comment: Date literals need to be in the ANSO compliant YYYYMMDD format when expressed as string literals. In your code you sometimes have '1/1/2021' and other times 1/1/2021. They will both return dates but not what you might think. The first is a date string literal, the second is going to do the calculation and will return Jan 1st 1900. Also, looping should be avoided here. This needs to be rewritten as a set based approach.

Comment: And a great read about the potential evils of using BETWEEN. https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common

Comment: This might be better to ask on [codereview.se]

Comment: You can definitely still get all of the rows without a WHILE statement.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Common Table Expressions (CTEs) in place of table variables, and this can help reduce and often speed up the code, such that we can get everything down to one (large) query with no loop:

```
WITH Scenes As  (
    SELECT A.IncNo, SceneSquad, ScDate 
    FROM DATABASE as A
    LEFT JOIN DATABASE as B
    On A.IncNo = B.IncNo
    WHERE ScDate BETWEEN '20210101' AND '20211031'
    AND A.DivID = ''
) 
, Assigned As (
    SELECT IncNo, Followupsquad, ASSIGNMENTDATE
    FROM DATABASE AS C
    LEFT JOIN DATABASE AS D
    ON D.IncNo = C.CIncNo
    WHERE SOMETHING = 'Y' AND DateRuled BETWEEN '20210101' AND '20211031'
    AND D.AssignD = ''
)
, Squads As (
    -- Removed row_number(), since it only seemed to be used for an index later
    SELECT Squad 
    FROM DATABASE
    WHERE UnitType = '' AND DivId = '' AND SquadStatus = 'A'
    -- also moved the ORDER BY to the final SELECT
)
SELECT sq.Squad As SqdNo
    , (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Scenes WHERE SceneSquad = sq.Squad) As Something
    , (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Assigned WHERE FollowupSquad = sq.Squad) As SomethingElse
FROM Squads sq
ORDER BY SqdNo
```

Each INSERT/SELECT for a table variable in the original question is instead now a CTE, and we then roll up the loop into correlated sub-queries (nested SELECTS).

The weakness here is it re-runs the `Scenes` and `Assigned` CTEs for each row, where the table variables effectively let the server cache those query results. The strength is the original table indexes are still available.

But that's just step one. We can improve this further to get the best of both worlds, using GROUP BY and JOINs. The trick is if we tried to use GROUP BY to get counts from both additional queries this in the same step, the row counts would be multiplied. However, we can use another CTE to force them to happen sequentially and get the right answers. If I skip past the prior CTEs to save space, it looks like this:

```
, SquadPlusSceneCounts As (
    SELECT sq.Squad, COUNT(*) As Something
    FROM Squads sq
    LEFT JOIN Scenes sc ON sc.SceneSquad = sq.Squad
    GROUP BY sq.Squad
)
SELECT sq.Squad As SqdNo, sq.Something, COUNT(*) As SomethingElse
FROM SquadPlusSceneCounts sq
LEFT JOIN Assigned a ON a.FollowupSquaud = sq.Squad
GROUP BY sq.Squad, sq.Something
ORDER BY sq.Squad
```

This will likely perform **much** better. The code is also simpler because we no longer need table variables or INSERT statements and I was able to remove the row_number() and loop. Finally, we preserved the intermediate logic and naming, so it will still be maintainable in a similar way (you can run most of the CTEs independently to verify them).

All of this was a straight-up translation of the code from the question. Better understanding of the data might also allow for logical improvements with further performance benefits and simpler code.

However, there's still the matter of the `@Date` variable; it's not at all clear what you were doing there. `SET @DATE = 1/1/2021 - 10/31/2021` makes no sense, and it wasn't used later. You may need an additional CTE that generates dates based on an initial value on the fly, that you can then also JOIN to. There are a number of ways to do this, and since I don't know it's even needed I'll leave it as an exercise.

One more thing. In many cases where CTEs are used, it's possible to wrap them up into nested SELECT queries instead. I tend to avoid this, because it's harder to maintain (you lose a level of naming or mnemonics and you can't run the CTE by itself as easily for testing/maintenance), but you can sometimes get a small performance benefit this way.

So for completeness, view the monstrosity below:

```
SELECT sq.Squad As SqdNo, sq.Something, COUNT(*) As SomethingElse
FROM (
    SELECT sq0.Squad, COUNT(*) As Something
    FROM (
        SELECT Squad 
        FROM DATABASE
        WHERE UnitType = '' AND DivId = '' AND SquadStatus = 'A'
    ) sq0
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT A.IncNo, SceneSquad, ScDate 
        FROM DATABASE as A
        LEFT JOIN DATABASE as B On A.IncNo = B.IncNo
        WHERE ScDate BETWEEN '20210101' AND '20211031'
            AND A.DivID = ''
    ) sc ON sc.SceneSquad = sq0.Squad
    GROUP BY sq0.Squad
) sq
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT IncNo, Followupsquad, ASSIGNMENTDATE
    FROM DATABASE AS C
    LEFT JOIN DATABASE AS D
    ON D.IncNo = C.CIncNo
    WHERE SOMETHING = 'Y' AND DateRuled BETWEEN '20210101' AND '20211031'
    AND D.AssignD = ''
) a ON a.FollowupSquaud = sq.Squad
GROUP BY sq.Squad, sq.Something
ORDER BY sq.Squad
```

But again, don't do this last part unless you have to.

---

As a complete aside, as bad as this is, it demonstrates why I'm not a fan or ORMs. As ugly as this code is, I don't want to think about trying to replicate it via ORM syntax. And even if you could, you'd still need to know how to write code like this in order be sure it's right... at which point you may just as well devote your time to learning good SQL.